# Setting up service cloud voice but getting errors following the guide on creating a package (if installed, supposed to create contact center)

Tags: package, servicecloud, partner

the guide is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_pt_developer_guide.meta/voice_pt_developer_guide/voice_pt_deploy_package.htm):

I am getting the following error when following this step:

Create a Package Version

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "<Package Name>" --codecoverage --installationkeybypass --wait 20
```

the errors I get are

1. sampleVendor: Not available for deploy for this organization
2. VoiceCall: Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex.
   __c )
3. Service_Cloud_Voice: In field: pageOrSobjectType - no CustomObject
   named VoiceCall found

and another error saying that the voicecall object is invalid (the msg is originally in another language)

Googling for the first error returns some answer about permission and version. But the user accounts of the dev-hub and the newly created or are administrators with access to api. I cannot find the version number of salesforce for both and so I cannot tell whether there is a mismatch.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you follow the setup instructions in [A Note About Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_pt_developer_guide.meta/voice_pt_developer_guide/voice_pt_scratch_org.htm) to configure your build org settings?

Comment: Are you intending to create a package to support a telephony system integration? The documentation you're referencing notes "This guide is for telephony providers who are creating a solution that integrates Service Cloud Voice with their telephony system". If you are setting up Service Cloud Voice as an end user, you are in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The scratch org is needed in a later step in this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_pt_developer_guide.meta/voice_pt_developer_guide/voice_pt_deploy_package.htm

Comment: I am working for a company intending to become a partner, not a salesforce user. I understand that I am creating a package and when a salesforce user or the scratch org created for testing has it installed, a contact center would show up.